# Content blinking on scroll

Tags: jquery, angular, scroll

I'm building a Angular 4 app with Materialize css framework and jquery, for now.

The problem i'm facing with is random blinking while scrolling. I made a script that will set div position to the top of the window when it gets to the top of the window.

I can provide a gif with a problem:
[image]

If you look at the small bar with "Can you stop blinking please" text, you will know what am I talking about.

HTML part:

```
<div id="list-header">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row-head row">
        <div class="col s3"><h5>Can</h5></div>
        <div class="col s3"><h5>You</h5></div>
        <div class="col s3"><h5>Stop blinking</h5></div>
        <div class="col s3"><h5>Please</h5></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
#list-header {
    border-top: 1px solid #D6E2EB;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D6E2EB;
    background: #ECF1F4;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    z-index:100;
}

#list-header.floating {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

JS part inside Angular 4 component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#list-header').offset().top) {
            $('#list-header').addClass('floating');
        }
        else {
            $('#list-header').removeClass('floating');
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: sebamed, there are several jQuery libraries that will do this for you automatically and reliably across different browsers.  To your specific issue  however, it may be a debouncing issue where in some cases the `else` part of your `ngOnInit()` function is true.  Scrolling events fires a lot of times.

Comment: Alexander Dixon, thanks for commenting! I will probably go for a [sticky](http://stickyjs.com/) library, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've found several libraries that provide similar solution.

Finally, to make it very simple and clean, I decided to use **ng-sticky** library,   found on github. [Link to library](https://github.com/jonasmedeiros/ng-sticky)

It simplifies whole process, and works flawlessly.

Install and enable guide is provided by creator of this awesome library, on his github page.